# My react multiselect keeps expanding as i add the options

Tags: css, react-bootstrap, react-select

I am using react select module to construct a multi-select dropbox. however as i add more than one option, the box keeps expanding, I want it to remain fixed. What css property should I change or is there another way to do this. Refer the pictures to get a clear understanding.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My form inline code for select:

```
<FormGroup
        controlId="ChannelType"
      >

        <div style={this.selectwidth}>
          <Select
            closeOnSelect={!stayOpen}
            multi={true}
            onChange={this.handleChannelSelect.bind(this)}
            options={ChannelTypes}
            placeholder="Select"
            removeSelected={false}
            simpleValue
          />
        </div>
        {' '}

      </FormGroup>
```

link for css of react-select :[link](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/dist/react-select.css)

Comment: try setting `autosize` prop to `false`

Answer (score 1):

Set `autosize` prop to `false`

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select#select-props